# Why does cURL sometimes require the "www." part of a URL to work, and vice versa?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, http-response-codes

For instance, using this code:

```
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_URL => "$url" ) );
 curl_exec( $curl );
 $header = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
 curl_close( $curl );
```

`$url = "http://upenn.edu"` will *not* work, while `$url = "http://www.upenn.edu"` will work.

Without the `www.` the response code I get is `0`, whereas with the `www.` it is `200`.

If I were to use PHP `get_headers("http://upenn.edu")`, I would get two errors:

> `Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

and

> `Warning: get_headers(http://upenn.edu) [function.get-headers]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

However, when I use the exact same code, `http://google.com` *will* work (as well as the expected `http://www.google.com`.)

Then, for a website such as `http://www.dogpile.com`, the `www.` part included returns a response code of `0` whereas *without* the `www.`, I get a `302`.

Why is this? and is there a better method to use in order to ensure reliable results (i.e., where a `www.` is not present, yet the response code is still returned?)

I am new to using cURL and dealing with headers and response codes, so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem here is on the web server side, not on the cURL side. There are a few websites that will only render something if the subdomain is `www`.

Comment: Same thing happens in the browser, no response: http://upenn.edu/ Nothing really to do with curl.

Comment: Okay, so it's definitely not from curl's ends, it's the server. That's good to know. I'm just a bit surprised at the outcome. I 'twasn't expecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, even asked because of using curl now, is actually something totally independent to curl. Other client http libraries will be the same with these examples because it is related to the domain name system and services running on a computer.

Curl is a HTTP library. If you do a HTTP request, by default you will try to connect to port 80 on a remote computer.

The remote computer is identified by an IP address. That is a number like `173.194.35.134` - you probably know that already.

Most often not the numbers are used but some domain names, for example `google.com` for `173.194.35.134`.

So telling curl to use the URI `http://google.com/` will open a connection to

```
173.194.35.134:80
```

The domain name system will resolve the domain `google.com` to the IP address.

Domain names can be organized in levels. Each level is separated by a dot `.`. The so called Top Level Domain (TLD) is the part most on the right, for `google.com` that is `com`. The Second Level Domain (SLD) is respectively `google` then. And with `www.google.com` you have another domain name, with three levels then. The `www` is commonly refered to as *Subdomain*.

The most important part here is that for every different domain the DNS system can return a different IP address.

Therefore `www.google.com` and `google.com` can be two totally different things. The `www` subdomain is only a common convention to name the webserver on a network organized with a `SLD.TLD`.

So by this being common you could try both and see which one works. However I would not try more than with and w/o `www`.

Comment: This is also a great answer. Thank you for elaborating on some of this. I think that's what I will do for now – try with and without the `www` until I hopefully come up with a more elegant way.

Comment: Well question is why don't you have the right domain at hand in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Not all domains treat `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` the same. *Usually* they do, but if you wanted to you could have two completely different websites on them.

Personally, I like to have all requests to `www.mydomains.com` redirected to the www-less version, but that's just my preference.

There is no realiable way of automatically detecting whether or not to use `www.`

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this.

Status of "0" means you did not get a response. This can be because of:

- url does not resolve the a server (e.g. if you don't put `www` but the server expects it - as Kolink says, you don't have to have websites on both)
- server does not respond (e.g. the url might get to the server, but the webserver doesn't give you a response)
- server responds with nothing (probably what is happening with dogpile; you are not passing appropriate headers so it knows you are a computer and no a human so is just bouncing you straight back)

Status of 200 means all is good.

Status of 3XX generally means moved. With 302, if you read the rest of the headers, you'll find a URL that the site has moved to, it's suggested you go there. (Note, cUrl can handle redirects automatically

The others you commonly get are 100 (continue), 404 (not found) and 500 (server error) but in practice, a server can return ANYTHING. including 418 "I'm a little teapot". (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324)

More reading:

- curl_getinfo() will tell you more about the last curl request. Will help yuo decipher why you got a status of "0"  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php
- curl_setopt() will allow youto tell curl to handle redirects. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
- Status codes and what they mean: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Thank you for explaining all this and providing some links. Very helpful. And to note, I did add in the `ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.16) Gecko/2009121601 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.16');` to account for a site like dogpile.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dig upenn.edu

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> upenn.edu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54604
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;upenn.edu.         IN  A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 18 17:37:18 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27

$ dig www.upenn.edu

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.upenn.edu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.upenn.edu.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.upenn.edu.      123 IN  CNAME   www.upenn.edu-dscg.edgesuite.net.
www.upenn.edu-dscg.edgesuite.net. 4782 IN CNAME a1165.dscg.akamai.net.
a1165.dscg.akamai.net.  4   IN  A   208.47.254.80
a1165.dscg.akamai.net.  4   IN  A   208.47.254.83

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 18 17:37:23 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 141
```

The University of Pennsylvania has neglected to setup a DNS record for the non-www variant of their domain name. It's odd that they've done so (and may be related to their CDN setup, which relies on a CNAME, which you can't have for the root level of a domain).

Nothing to do with cURL, just upenn.edu's DNS setup.

Comment: A good webmistress keeps running a HTTPD on `upenn.edu:80` redirecting to the `www.upenn.edu` domain - the webserver must not do anything else than giving redirect responses.

Comment: Nothing odd, just old fashioned. In the old days it was common to leave the "root" name unresolved, as clients would generally try to connect to ftp.domain.tla or wais.domain.tla or archie.domain.tla or mx.domain.tla, etc.  Once the web buried everything else, including good sense, typing 'www' became too geeky, and so to keep up with browser-fed user expectations, many domains were "forced" into having their roots be resolvable (have A records).

Comment: @arayq2 That it was once non-odd doesn't make it non-odd today.

Comment: I agree. The mainstreaming of the web has made it normal to gravitate to wasteful, inefficent and often stupid "solutions".  These days, doing the right thing can be distinctly odd.